# The solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}-x\tan(y-x)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}-x\tan(y-x)=1$ will be?

For solving such problems first we should see if the equation is in variable seperable form or not. Obviously here it is not. So I tried to see if it can be made to variable seperable by substitution, but substituting $y-x=z$ would not give the answer as there is one $x$ remaining outside that $\tan(y-x)$. Also it is not a homogenous nor is getting converted into homogenous form so that I could substitute $y=vx$ or $x=vy$. So which method should I use here? I am getting wrong answer everytime, please help in dealing with this. Atleast provide me a hint.

Comment: **Hint:** Try letting $v = y-x$.

Comment: I have tried that, but the variable x in multiplication with the tan function gives me the problem. I have mentioned it in my question.

Comment: You get a Separable equation as $\displaystyle \int \cot v ~.dv = \int x ~dx$. What is the problem with that?

Comment: OH!! I am really, really sorry for such a silly question. I was not solving it but was just predicting the answer by looking at it. I got it when i took pen in my hand.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y-x=z$ will give the solution.

let $y-x=z$ then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1+\dfrac{dz}{dx}$

Now,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}-x\cdot\tan(y-x)&=1\\
\Rightarrow1+\dfrac{dz}{dx}-x\cdot\tan z&=1\\
\Rightarrow\dfrac{dz}{dx}&=x\cdot\tan z\\
\displaystyle\int\cot z\ dz&=\displaystyle\int x\ dx+k\\
\Rightarrow\ln{\left|\sin{z}\right|}&=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+k\\
\Rightarrow\ln{\left|\sin{z}\right|}^2&=x^2+2k\\
\Rightarrow\sin^2{(y-x)}&=e^{x^2+2k}\\
\Rightarrow\sin^2{(y-x)}&=c\cdot e^{x^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Your decision to substitute $z=y-x$ is a good one.

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives:
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=1\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}-1$$
Therefore, rearranging gives:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dx}+1$$
Substituting gives a separable ODE:
$$\frac{dz}{dx}+1-x\tan{z}=1$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=x\tan{z}$$
Can you continue?